# DisplayFor helper does not populate records from database in delete view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

i want to delete a record from my database , but in the delete confirm view

the DisplayFor Helper Does Not Show any record from my database

DisplayNameFor does work correctly , i don't know what i'm doing wrong,

any help would be appreciated.

here is my code.

Controller Code :

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new Database1Entities())
            {

                var tooltip = db.tooltip_tbl.Find(id);
                db.tooltip_tbl.Remove(tooltip);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

the view code :

```
@model WebApplication7.Models.tooltip_tbl

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>

<div>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => item.Title)</dt>

    <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Title)</dd>

    <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => item.Info)</dt>

    <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Info)</dd>

</dl>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, your GET action method is not passing anything to your delete view. So the Model of your view is actually `null` and the `DisplayFor` helper method is graciously doing the null check for you , hence you are not getting any null reference exception.

You need to pass a valid tootip object to your view, in your GET action.

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var tooltip = db.tooltip_tbl.Find(id);
    return View(tooltip);
}
```

Comment: Assuming OP is using the default route, then the `id` is added as a route value (in the `BeginForm()`) so the hidden input is not necessary.

Comment: Yes. That is true.